# ¿Por que al ingresar un dato en mi BD me coloca un espacio al inicio?

Tags: sql-server, vb.net

tengo un problema con el mantenimiento de un sistema, al insertar un nuevo dato me coloca un espacio al inicio al momento en que se guarda.
Ejemplo: ingreso en un [textbox](/questions/tagged/textbox) **"Psicoterapia"** pero en la base de datos me lo guarda como **" Psicoterapia"** con un espacio al inicio.
Quisiera saber como puedo solucionar ese error

### conexion.Open()

```
                comando = New SqlCommand("INSERT INTO dbo.Alumno(IDAlumno,NombreCompleto,Correo,ContactoEmergencia,Telefono,
                                   TelEmergencia)" & "VALUES('" & NumeroCuenta.Text & " ','" & txtNombreA.Text & "' ,'" & txtCorreoA.Text & "',
                                '" & txtEmergencia.Text & "' ,'" & cel1.Text & "', '" & cel2.Text & "')", conexion)
                comando.Parameters.AddWithValue("@IDAlumno", NumeroCuenta.Text)
                comando.Parameters.AddWithValue("@NombreCompleto", txtNombreA.Text)
                comando.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Correo", txtCorreoA.Text)
                comando.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ContactoEmergencia", txtEmergencia.Text)
                comando.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Telefono", cel1.Text)
                comando.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TelEmergencia", cel2.Text)
                comando.ExecuteNonQuery() ##
```

Asi es como lo tengo para insertar

Comment: habría que ver código para ser mas específico, pero siempre podes hacer un trim() antes del insert

Comment: en tu  `INSERT` puedes hacer lo siguiente **INSERT INTO tableName(columnaUno)  VALUES(LTRIM(RTRIM(valueUno)))** con ltrim eliminas espacios iniciales y con rtrim eliminas espacios finales

Comment: Gracias Totales

Answer (score 1):

> **Desde SQL Server te puedes auxiliar de las siguientes funciones:**

1. `LTRIM()` Que me sirve para eliminar los espacios al inicio de una cadena
2. `RTRIM()` Que me ayuda para eliminar los espacios al final de una cadena

Pueden ambos trabajar mezclados y usarlos como en el ejemplo siguiente

```
 INSERT INTO tableName(columnaUno) VALUES(LTRIM(RTRIM(valorUno)));
```

De tal manera que aunque yo escriba lo siguiente:

```
INSERT INTO tableName(columnaUno)
values 
(LTRIM(RTRIM('      daniel  '))), (' alfredo');
```

El resultado final será

select * from tableName;

```
columnaUno
daniel  
 alfredo    
pedro
```

> Daniel aunque se declaró con espacios en ambos lados, le fueron
>   borrados por las 2 funciones, como el registro Alfredo se le agregó un
>   espacio pero no se le paso ninguna función, dicho espacio al inicio se
>   mantuvo